# How to use filterspecs in Django 1.4+?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am deploying a project which must be run on Django 1.4, but some pip dependencies of the project use `django.contrib.admin.filterspecs` for defining custom templatetags which is only available in Django < 1.4. The requirements arn't still updated to supoort Django 1.4.

Is there a way to use filterspecs in Django 1.4+?

Comment: Could you name those dependencies that require `django.contrib.admin.filterspecs`?

Comment: @alecxe django-db-log, which is no longer maintained, but unfortunately used in the project

Comment: Thanks. I think you should consider getting rid of the dependency by switching to sentry or using django's built-in logging system.